# Highlighting menu item on selection

Tags: asp.net, menu, highlighting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ASP.NET: Highlight menu item of current page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067944/asp-net-highlight-menu-item-of-current-page)

I'm trying to highlight or change background of a menu item which I have selected in the navigation menu. The code is as follows:

```
<asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server"  CssClass="menu" OnMenuItemClick="high()" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
               <StaticSelectedStyle CssClass="SelectedStyle" />
                <Items>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx"   Text="Home"/>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Forecast.aspx" Text="Forecast"/>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/MI.aspx" Text="MI"/>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Statistics.aspx" Text="Statistics"/>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Trends.aspx" Text="Trends"/>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" Text="About"/>
                </Items>
            </asp:Menu>
        </div>
    </div>
      <script>
      function high()
 {
 var selItem=document.getElementById("NavigationMenu");
  selItem.style.bgcolor='red';
   }

 </script>
```

It doesn't seem to work.What am I doing wrong in it?

After the edit my code looks like this

```
    <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server"  CssClass="menu"  EnableViewState="false"               IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
               <staticselectedstyle backcolor="LightBlue"
      borderstyle="Solid"
      bordercolor="Black"
      borderwidth="1"/> 
                <Items>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx"   Text="Home"/>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Forecast.aspx" Text="Forecast"/>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/MI.aspx" Text="MI"/>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Statistics.aspx" Text="Statistics"/>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Trends.aspx" Text="Trends"/>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" Text="About"/>
                </Items>
```

still no effect

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067944/asp-net-highlight-menu-item-of-current-page

Comment: Thanks @LukeHutton but it didn't still work for me..

Comment: (For future searchers) According to an update on the linked-to page the link you have to set `IncludeStyleBlock="true"`