# Highlight active menu selection

Tags: jquery, css, vb.net, twitter-bootstrap

Using the solution provided here [How to highlight active page in a masterpage menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17060426/how-to-highlight-active-page-in-a-masterpage-menu) I was able to get my active menu items to show correctly on the navigation menu. I am using VB.NET with a masterpage. The following code resides in the masterpage:

```
<script>
       function equalHeight(group) {
           tallest = 0;
           group.each(function () {
               thisHeight = $(this).height();
               if (thisHeight > tallest) {
                   tallest = thisHeight;
               }
           });
           group.each(function () { $(this).height(tallest); });
       }

       jQuery(document).ready(function () {
           App.init();
           // Call to set active menu selecttion
           var str = location.href.toLowerCase();
           $(".nav li a").each(function () {
               if (str.indexOf($(this).attr("href").toLowerCase()) > -1) {
                   $("li.active").removeClass("active");
                   $(this).parent().addClass("active");
               }
           });
           equalHeight($(".img-thumbnail"));

       });
</script>
```

ADDED: If a section ("Tools" for instance) has multiple pages that belong under it, can you think of any way to have the above code select the correct active menu item?

Answer (score 0):

Use this Javascript

```
 function LoadActiveMenu()
    {
        var str=location.href.toLowerCase();
        $("li a").each(function() {
            if (str.indexOf($(this).attr("href").toLowerCase()) > -1) {
                $("li.active").removeClass("active");
                $(this).parent().addClass("active");
            }
        });
        $("li.active").parents().each(function(){
            if ($(this).is("li")){
                $(this).addClass("active");
            }
        });
     }
```

and call this function on body load event like below

```
<body onload="LoadActiveMenu();">
</body>
```