# ASP.NET Masterpage nav current page Css

Tags: html, css, asp.net, master-pages, nav

I am trying to set the background color of the LinkButton in my **nav bar** according to what page is currently displayed.  I'd like it to be orange if on that page and black if not.

I have this for now:

```
<nav>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkB1TSUser" runat="server" OnClick="lnkB1TSUser_Click">B1TS User</asp:LinkButton>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkClient" runat="server" OnClick="lnkClient_Click">Client</asp:LinkButton>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkUserClient" runat="server" OnClick="lnkUserClient_Click">User Client</asp:LinkButton>
</nav>
```

I know how to do CSS in general but I have no idea how to set the specific page that I'm on to have the background.

If I made two CSS classes active and inactive:

```
.active {
  background-color: orange;
}
.inactive {
  background-color: black;
}
```

Would that help me to implement this?  It would just be really great if I could highlight (in orange) the page that I'm actively on.  And I have no idea how to do this with master pages.  Help would be very much appreciated.

At the moment the onclick event is just for navigating between pages.

Comment: Maybe [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17060426/how-to-highlight-active-page-in-a-masterpage-menu) will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a big fan of putting styling in code, but I think you have no choice except using server-side code or Javascript. Here's how to do it with C# server-side code, using `LinkButton`'s `CommandArgument` to store the page's name:

```
<nav>
    <asp:LinkButton CommandArgument="page.aspx" ID="lnkB1TSUser" runat="server" OnClick="lnkB1TSUser_Click">B1TS User</asp:LinkButton>
    <asp:LinkButton CommandArgument="page2.aspx" ID="lnkClient" runat="server" OnClick="lnkClient_Click">Client</asp:LinkButton>
    <asp:LinkButton CommandArgument="page3.aspx" ID="lnkUserClient" runat="server" OnClick="lnkUserClient_Click">User Client</asp:LinkButton>
</nav>
<%
    foreach(var control in new LinkButton[] { lnkB1TSUser, lnkClient, lnkUserClient })
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.EndsWith(control.CommandArgument))
            control.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange;
    }
%>
```